# How to recover finality after validator "forced" it due to high finality lag (500+ blocks)

Tags: grandpa, finality

Following a relay runtime upgrade for westend 103000 (which contained a broken migration of the beefy keys), our chain stopped finalizing blocks (all validators, except 1, had the wrong keys on-chain).

While preparing the solution, we left the relay **pass 500+ blocks of finality lag**, which "forces" the validator to finalize the blocks that are 500+ behind. This helped to recover the network.

However, the other nodes (RPC nodes) are now refusing the finality:

```
2024-03-01 09:32:25.357 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker grandpa: GRANDPA voter error: safety invariant has been violated: Invalid operation in the pending changes tree: Finalized descendent of Tree node without finalizing its ancestor(s) first    
2024-03-01 09:26:29.306 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker sc_service::task_manager: Essential task `grandpa-voter` failed. Shutting down service.
```

(Also) On another network, with same conditions, we fixed it by using the only valid validator and note_stalled. The RPC nodes are also refusing finality:

```
2024-03-01 07:51:21.022 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync::import-queue: Justification import failed for hash = 0xf27b397021806e4bccfe6e0ab3f19e768f3f0495b71187ba8aab3d63bd7dcf28 with number = 12977265 coming from node = PeerId("12D3KooWQRVQqakRuPxwLoaRHTpEaTDQSX9MqAatJ2Jgqd5aucvf") with error: Import failed: bad justification for header: invalid signature for precommit in grandpa justification
2024-03-01 07:51:21.022  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sync:  Invalid justification provided by 12D3KooWQRVQqakRuPxwLoaRHTpEaTDQSX9MqAatJ2Jgqd5aucvf for #0xf27b…cf28
```

How can we **force nodes** to accept the justification or to simply consider those blocks as final ?

Answer (score 0):

The first error on the RPC nodes is really weird, because it means that some later validator set change was finalized without finalizing a previous one. Is this only happening on the RPC nodes, i.e. the validators are working fine? Also what happens if you try to sync from scratch, does it lead to the same error?

What happened to the session keys in the migration (if you can dump the value of `session.queuedKeys` from pjs-ui)? I think that from GRANDPA POV probably all the keys (except one) ended up resolving to the same value, which leads to all kinds of invariants being violated.

Comment: You can see the details of the incident there: https://moonsonglabs.notion.site/2024-01-Stagenet-Alphanet-Finality-stall-8e2e6513347a48229151363cf13788d5?pvs=4
What happened was the same as on Westend (and Rococo maybe?), where the migration concatenated the beefy key to the session keys of each validator. The issue was that this migration was included in multiple release without a versioning system to protect multiple runs

Comment: Also, we are currently mostly interested in finding a solution for nodes to catch-up with finalization, as nodes cannot sync it (even from scratch) anymore

Comment: In the incident writeup there are only 2 keys shown, so it doesn't allow me to figure out if all of the other validators have the same (invalid) GRANDPA key. But since they were able to finalize, I assume that's probably the case. I am not really sure how to recover from this since all grandpa invariants have been broken, it finalized something with an invalid set of keys. This would require some manual hacks to revert finality, in which case all nodes on the network would have to resync anyway.

Comment: I didn't write all the keys but all of them except the first one were broken. The finality went on on one of the network because of the 500 limit of finality lag, and on the other one because of "forced" finalization using grandpa.noteStalled and para force approval.

You are suggesting a manual hack, do you know how ?

Comment: Resyncing from scratch is not solving the issue as the node will refuse the finalization and get stuck. I suppose it requires modifying the code to force the node to bypass it but I was hoping there would already be a solution for that

Comment: No I don't really have any clear suggestion that could be applied for this in a generic way. Any hack would have to be applied directly in the GRANDPA code (either upstream or on a fork you maintain), and would have to stay there forever for people resyncing. I think the root issue is that critical invariants have been violated, and the node produced an invalid finality proof since there were a majority of duplicate validator keys in the set AFAIU.

Comment: Thank you André. In that case, should we remove the forced finality after 500 blocks? As we don't provide solution to recover from it after

Comment: I don't think so because the root problem wasn't the forced finality, but the fact that the validator set was in an invalid state (due to the borked session keys migration). If the validator set was in a good state and finality had stalled for some other reason, the system would have handled the forced finality after 500 blocks fine AFAIU.